# How to set system wide settings in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, configuration

For multi-users desktops, I need to set-up some preferences in Eclipse.

As an example, I need to activate those 2 preferences by default :
General>Workspace>Refresh using native hooks or polling
General>Workspace>Refresh on access

I've found that by checking them and closing eclipse, it is saved to `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` which contains :

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
refresh.enabled=true
refresh.lightweight.enabled=true
version=1
```

What would be the way to set it system wide? All users, all workspaces.

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do it, except maybe tweaking the sytem login process with scripts to copy the settings to the current user and writing an eclipse plugin to copy the settings to each new workspace. Settings in eclipse are workspace specific (and it sucks sometimes)

Comment: @kostja: Settings in Eclipse can be of different scopes (e.g. user, instance, workspace or project). Example: You can configure your proxy authentication in one workspace and it is afterwards also used in another workspace, because that is a user setting.

Comment: @Bananenweizen - glad that i'm not right about that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Google Workspace Mechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/) to share these settings. Or have your IDE and workspaces managed by [Yoxos](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/) (which does a lot of other things besides only preferences).

In pure Eclipse, there is no way to do this by configuration only.

Comment: great plugin, never heard of it before. And public profiles for eclipse are free at Yoxos. Thanks for sharing, +1